# Is it legal to send a credit card number over the air from an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, sdk, credit-card

We have a situation where a client would like us to send a CC number to a secure web service via https from our iPhone app. The CC is not being processed on the phone- it just needs to be sent to the web service where it is later processed on the server.

What is the legality of doing this? Will Apple still approve the app with this kind of functionality? What kind of encryption needs to be applied to the credit card #?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably *legal* to do it - Apple doesn't make the law.

Comment: Since you're using https isn't everything already encrypted?

Comment: Just make sure that your iPhone application is PCI compliant.  For instance, don't save the number in plain text on the phone itself. https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org

Comment: This is not really a coding question and probably doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 3):

There is no one correct answer, since the security requirements depend on what kind of credit card (Mastercard, Visa, etc.), and it looks like you only want to transmit the one card number.

You are required to follow PCI compliance to transmit the CC number.

This link should get you looking at the right place: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/merchants/how_to_be_compliant.php

Comment: Thanks a lot. The client has PCI compliance on the website but I'm not sure if this extends to the app.